# Videos got slower after installing MESA, how to fix?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, mesa

Following some online recommendations to improve performance i installed MESA stable version but after that i only got was videos stopping being smooth/fluid.. I tried then the edgy version, but nothing changed. 
After that i uninstall it by changing kernel and using purge command but that didn’t fix the problem.

Aspire V3-551G

> Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7640G]
>   Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M
>   Series]

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by installing "MESA stable version "? You can follow some online recommendations to remove it.

Comment: Mesa Stable 13.0.X , i already removed it, i think.